# Product within a sum

Tags: summation

How would I input the following sum into *Mathematica*?
[image]

Comment: Never mind, it diverges. How would it work though if I added a *(-1) ^i within the product?

Comment: no, my mistake. they're both supposed to be an i

Comment: How is this question related to `Mathematica`?

Comment: Isn't the product vanishing?

Answer (score 3):

You should check [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SumsAndProducts.html) out.

For sum the syntax is

```
Sum[f,{i,imin,imax}]
```

and for Product

```
Product[f,{i,imin,imax}]
```

Combining both

```
Sum[Product[f,{i,imin,imax}],{i,imin,imax}]
```

For example,

```
Sum[Product[i^2, {i, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}]
```

> n (n!)^2

Answer (score 1):

The sum/product

```
Sum[Product[1/2 2^(k - 1)/2^k, {k, 1, n}], {k, 1, n}]
Limit[%,n->Infinity]
(*0*)
```

vanishs!